# How to truncate a HTML fragment to a given length(for preview) in Java?

Tags: java, html, truncate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [html truncator in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496372/html-truncator-in-java)

How to truncate a HTML fragment to a given length(for preview) in Java ? I'm develop a personal weblog. 
I want to use some html parser to do that, e.g. use Xerces-J ?